# A pondering thought about mysql_query and such

Tags: mysql

So in a year or so `mysql_query` will be gone in the newer versions of PHP. That being said the ever-so-used `mysql_query` used on sites will stop working on those who update.

Will this also affect things like `mysql_num_rows` and other functions? I mean, what alternative to `mysql_query` is there? I know there is `mysqli` but how is it different to that of `mysql`?

Comment: There are already tons of questions on the topic of PDO vs MySQLi vs mysql_* on stackoverflow.

Comment: mysqli and PDO are alternatives.  Take a look at the PHP manpages, such as http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php to get a sense of how they compare to mysql.  The main thing they both do is support prepared statements, which are super important for avoiding sql injection attacks on databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The whole (original) mysql extension is going away, not just the `mysql_query` function. The list of functions involved can be seen at:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php