# Displaying all tables in a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I display out all the information in a database (All tables and records) using PHP? I read displaying tables as HTML table but how do I do it for all the tables?

I tried the example here:
http://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php

But it shows the table names, how do I also display all the values?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

If you want to pull all `tables` with the `values` in `mysql`, you can use the following code:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect ("localhost", "DB_USER", "DB_PASSWORD"); //your mysql connection  
    mysql_select_db('DB_NAME') or die( "Unable to select database"); //your db name 

    $tables = mysql_query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='DB_NAME'"); //pull tables from theh databsase
    while ($table= mysql_fetch_row($tables)) { 
        $rsFields = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table[0]); 
        while ($field = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsFields)) { 
            echo $table[0].".".$field["Field"].", "; //prints out all columns 
        } 
        echo $table[0];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table[0]; //prints out tables name
        $result = mysql_query($query); 
        PullValues($result); //call function to get all values
    }  


    //function to pull all values from tables
    function PullValues($result) 
    {     
        if($result == 0) 
        { 
            echo "<b>Error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."</b>"; 
        } 
        elseif (@mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
        { 
            echo("<b>Query completed. No results returned.</b><br>"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "<table border='1'> 
                <thead> 
                <tr><th>[Num]</th>"; 
            for($i = 0;$i < mysql_num_fields($result);$i++) 
            { 
                echo "<th>" . $i . "&nbsp;-&nbsp;" . mysql_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>"; 
            } 
            echo "  </tr> 
                </thead> 
                <tbody>"; 
            for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) 
            { 
                echo "<tr><td>[$i]</td>"; 
                $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
                for($j = 0;$j < mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)  
                { 
                    echo("<td>" . $row[$j] . "</td>"); 
                } 
                echo "</tr>"; 
            } 
            echo "</tbody> 
            </table>"; 
        }  //end else 
    }  
?>
```

I am using this and works fine in `mysql`, for `mysqli` you need to tweak it a very little.

Comment: This is `mysql_query` based, not `mysqli`.

Comment: @AlphaMale Thanks it works, for displaying i used mysql instead of mysqli. It works fine so far.

Comment: `mysql_query` is dangerous, deprecated, and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Please stop using it for anything new. The `mysql` tag is for MySQL in general and has nothing to do with `mysql_query` in PHP.

Comment: @tadman will mysqli_query be good for that? because i see it just now that mysql extensions are going away: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451967/a-pondering-thought-about-mysql-query-and-such

Comment: Use `mysqli` only if PDO is not available and cannot be installed. It's basically the new baseline.

Answer (score 4):

Okay got it ..  try this

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "DB");

$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES");
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $table = $row[0];
    echo '<h3>', $table, '</h3>';
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
    echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
    $column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table`");
    echo '<tr>';
    while ($row3 = $column->fetch_row()) {
        echo '<th>' . $row3[0] . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    while ($row2 = $result1->fetch_row()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($row2 as $key => $value) {
            echo '<td>', $value, '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table><br />';
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: it could be that aandroidtest did not enable the following inside php.ini: 
extension=php_mysqli.dll 
and i also recommend enabling the pdo extension

Answer (score -1):

you can use the recursive function to display the tree Structure of your database.

Here is the a sample code from  http://webcodingeasy.com/PHP/Simple-recursive-function-to-print-out-database-tree-structure

```
<?php
function print_menu($id = 0) 
{
    // get all records from database whose parent is $id
    $result = $query->select_result("*", "table", "where parent = '".$id."'");
    //check if there are any results
    if($result != 0)
    {
        echo "<ul> n";
        while($row = $query->fetch($result))
        {
            //print result and call function to check if it has children
            echo "<li>".$row['name']."</li> n";
            print_menu($row['ID']);
        }
        echo "</ul> n";
    }
}
print_menu();
?>
```