# Query mysql and export data as CSV in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have myssql db with different tables. The data between the tables are linked and I retrieve and display them by using the userid. I used the reference from [PHP MYSQLi Displaying all tables in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618304/php-mysqli-displaying-all-tables-in-a-database)

But how do I export this information as a csv file? I have tried instead of echo changed it to a string and print the string to a csv file but it is not working.

I have also tried the example from:
http://sudobash.net/php-export-mysql-query-to-csv-file/

But I can see the data but on top there is also junk (like `"<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>"`
 etc) inside the csv file.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to write each MySQL row to a CSV file, you could use the built in PHP5 function `fputcsv`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM table');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($row as $val) {
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Which should return a comma separated string for each row written to `file.csv`:

```
row1 val1, row1 val2
row2 val1, row2 val2 
etc..
```

Also be sure to check permissions for the directory you are writing to.

Comment: @dcd08 Thanks I actually have tried this but the issue  is at the bottom of the csv file there are also junk printed like "<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>"
etc Any idea what is causing it?

Comment: Ok done, i have to put ob_start() at the top and this is resolved.

Comment: Can anyone post an example/link on how to deal with search box query alongside csv/xls export? I would like to use search box as query and $_GET["search"] variable, then retrieve data from mysql, display in the table and then export to xls/csv. As far as I understand there should be one search box input and two submit buttons...

Answer (score 12):

This is a solution that incorporates the headers or field names by using [MySQLi's](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) `fetch_fields` function -

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = $db->query($query);
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$headers = $result->fetch_fields();
foreach($headers as $header) {
    $head[] = $header->name;
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($head)); 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
```

This is also a modification [of a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv) where a similar solution was suggested but the headers part did not work for me, so I changed the method of retrieving them.  Credit is due to @Jrgns

Answer (score 4):

You can try to utilize MySql [`INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html) clause:

```
SELECT *
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/tablename.csv'
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   FROM tablename
  WHERE userid = 1
```

Comment: This does not add column names to the first row of csv. please also suggest changes in the above method so that it can export the column names as well.

Answer (score 1):

for creating and downloading a csv file from a mysqli query (using object oriented) I think this would help.

This is a Class that connects with the database and the functions will do whatever you want using mysqli and PHP. In this case, calling this class (require or include), just use the "downloadCsv()" function.

As an example, this would be the "class.php" file:

```
<?php
class DB{

private $con;

//this constructor connects with the database
public function __construct(){
$this->con = new mysqli("Your_Host","Your_User","Your_Pass","Your_DatabaseName");

if($this->con->connect_errno > 0){
    die('There was a problem [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
    }
}

//create the function that will download a csv file from a mysqli query

public function downloadCsv(){

$count = 0;
$header = "";
$data = "";
//query
$result = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM Your_TableName");
//count fields
$count = $result->field_count;
//columns names
$names = $result->fetch_fields();
//put column names into header
foreach($names as $value) {
    $header .= $value->name.";";
    }
}
//put rows from your query
while($row = $result->fetch_row())  {
    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $value)       {
        if(!isset($value) || $value == "")  {
            $value = ";"; //in this case, ";" separates columns
    } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . ";"; //if you change the separator before, change this ";" too
        }
        $line .= $value;
    } //end foreach
    $data .= trim($line)."\n";
} //end while
//avoiding problems with data that includes "\r"
$data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);
//if empty query
if ($data == "") {
    $data = "\nno matching records found\n";
}
$count = $result->field_count;

//Download csv file
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $header."\n".$data."\n";

}
?>
```

After creating the "class.php" file, in this example, use that function on "download.php" file:

```
<?php
//call the "class.php" file
require_once 'class.php';
//instantiate DB class
$export = new DB();
//call function
$export->downloadCsv();
?>
```

After download, open the file with MS Excel.

I hope this help you, I think I wrote it well, I didn't feel comfortable with the text and code field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
function addRowToCsv(& $csvString, $cols) {
    $csvString .= implode(',', $cols) . PHP_EOL; //Edits must be 6 characters - all I added was a "." before the =. :-)
}

$csvString = '';
$first = true;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if ($first === true) {
        $first = false;
        addRowToCsv($csvString, array_keys($row));
    }
    addRowToCsv($csvString, $row);
}

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=MyCsvFile.csv');

echo $csvString;
```

Notice that the first argument to addRowToCsv is passed by reference. This is not required and you could easily use a return value, but this is just how I would do it.

If you want to save the output to a file rather than serving it as a download then use the above but replace

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=MyCsvFile.csv');

echo $csvString;
```

With..

```
file_put_contents('MyCsvFile.csv', $csvString);
```