# No File created with SELECT * INTO OUTFILE

Tags: php, mysql, database, download

I work on a shared hosting and I have to export a MySQL database with PHP, because I have a client who wants the ability to import and export their database.

I have searched the Internet and what I found looks really simple, I created the following file in a sub-directory of my hosting.

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";

    if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
        die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }

    $tableName  = 'questions';
    $backupFile = 'backup/mytable.sql';
    $query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
?>
```

I tried it out, and it seemed to work (no errors in `error_log` file.), but it created no file.

I tried different output folders, files and filetypes but that changed anything.

I found out that others had a probem with `INTO OUTFILE` because the mysql user has not enough permissions. How can I find that out? Shouldn't it give me an error then?

Is there a simple (or not simple) alternative to `INTO OUTFILE`, that I can run with PHP and creates a file I can import later?

Comment: If I remember correctly, INTO OUTFILE is relative to a directory on the database _server's_ file system. Not the one that your script is running on. Since you're on shared hosting, it is likely that they are not on the same servers, or if they are, then you would need to use an absolute path to where you want the file.

Comment: Does `mysqli_query` return `true`? If not, what's the result of `mysqli_error`? And where are you looking for the file? (On the DB server, I'm hoping...)

Comment: @JonStirling I searched for the file in the relative directory, and searched the whole server with the cPanel search filemanager

Comment: @KarlHofmann Like I said, it's probably not on that server (or if it is, perhaps you don't have read access to it)

Comment: @MattGibson mysqli_error gives me nothing, the mysql_query returns false, I searched on the Fileserver, where the PHP Script is located on, I don't know but I think I don't have access to my DB-Filesystem.

Comment: If the query failed, then mysqli_error should be giving you at least something.

Comment: @MattGibson Had a typo... it returned: Access denied for user '...t'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
So I assume, I don't have enough permissions right?

Comment: @KarlHofmann Yup. I guess you don't have permissions to output files to the DB server (which wouldn't be unusual on any hosting, let alone shared hosting...)

Comment: @MattGibson Is there any Chance to get this data? Maybe without saving to the server, sending the data directly to the browser? (Idk if that is possible)

Comment: @KarlHofmann I've only ever seen people [hand-rolling stuff using fputcsv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391528/query-mysql-and-export-data-as-csv-in-php), but I imagine there are libraries for it...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://www.murawski.ch/2011/04/mysql-backup-per-php-script/) solved my Problem. 
I had to change some little things (and mysql to mysqli).
Not the best solution, but it works on shared hostings too.

Comment: do not include link. Link could be broken in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Remove single quote from **$backupFile**

Like this

```
 $query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE $backupFile FROM $tableName";
```

Otherwise it will read it as a string not as a variable where you're storing your backupfile path.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$backupFile = 'backup/mytable.sql';
```

to

```
$backupFile = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/mytable.sql';
```

Then, assuming that DB and PHP engine are running on the same host, you can read the $backupFile