# How do you create and save a csv file from a php while loop to a specific directory?

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to create a csv file out of this and save it to a file in my directory. How would you accomplish this? Thanks.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT code, count FROM products WHERE active = '1' ORDER BY code Asc") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $code = $row['code'];
    $quantity = $row['quantity'];
}
```

Comment: 1) open a file `fopen()`, in whatever location on disk you like (or have the privileges for)  2) look up `fputcsv()` 3) close the file

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Perhaps something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391528/query-mysql-and-export-data-as-csv-in-php might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// open the file for writing

> $file = fopen('dir path/filename_to_be_saved.csv', 'w');

// save the column headers

> fputcsv($file, array('code', ‘quantity'));

// save row data

> while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
> $code = $row['code'];
> $quantity = $row['quantity'];
> $csv_row = array($code, $quantity);
> fputcsv($file, $csv_row);
> }

// Close the file

> fclose($file);